# Issue with "Faulting application name: dotnet.exe, "

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core

I have a .netcore api application hosted in IIS.

My problem is my api sometimes return CORS for no reason as i checked the event viewer it says:

Faulting application name: dotnet.exe, version: 2.1.30411.1, time stamp: 0x61145604
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.14393.4350, time stamp: 0x606eb12a
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000dc602
Faulting process id: 0x90c8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d7a3aea3b721ad
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 5d9880c5-2b58-46fe-ab80-c1e48327be77
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constant crashes of ASP.NET Core app on IIS with Windows10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48147559/constant-crashes-of-asp-net-core-app-on-iis-with-windows10)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the stdout enabled in your config file and also Try adding full permissions for IIS user to the wwwroot......\XYZ-v.json.

For more details, i found a similar thread might useful to you, please check this [so thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48147559/constant-crashes-of-asp-net-core-app-on-iis-with-windows10) and if useful, Thanks to [Maciejek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5576168/maciejek)